# Implement an SSO Service Provider for my SAAS application and integrate with Azure AD SAML

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml

I want to integrate with a client's Azure AD SSO using SAML. From what I've understood so far, the Azure AD is an identity provider (Idp), I would have to write a Service Provider(SP)and get it registered at the client's Azure AD. Then there is the exchange of SAML Assertion token through HTTP Post and Redirect which will need to be checked if their cryptographic signatures are valid. My question is how do I go about implementing this Service Provider in my application and is it even a good idea to write my own SP and not use any of the cloud solutions?

Answer (score 0):

> is it even a good idea to write my own SP

Implementing a SAMLv2 standards-compliant Service Provider would be quite an effort. There are several products/projects in different programming languages available for this.

If your application infrastructure includes Apache http server, you may just use [mod_auth_mellon](https://github.com/UNINETT/mod_auth_mellon). I'm not sure if choosing a cloud solution like AWS cognito will work well in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the SAML toolkit for .Net from OneLogin if you want to implement the SP yourself: https://developers.onelogin.com/saml/c-and-aspnet

Shibboleth SP is a stable implementation that works well with Apache. It could be installed in a reverse proxy if you want a central SP that is the gatekeeper for all services: https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SP3/Home

SimpleSAMLphp may be used as an SP, IdP or both for proxy functionality: https://simplesamlphp.org/

I have experience using Shibboleth SP running on an Apache reverse proxy and Microsoft ADFS as the IdP. It works very well.